# How can I make a function run every time cd successfully changes to another directory within sh on FreeBSD?

Tags: sh, freebsd

I'm using sh as my shell on FreeBSD but I want to be able to have a pretty prompt like the one bash gives me on Ubuntu. There are two things that the FreeBSD implementation of sh seems to lack as far as PS1 escape characters go:

1. The `\w` works but does not expand `$HOME` to `~`, so this is something I have already hacked up myself
2. I can use PS1 to update the prompt on the terminal, but as far as I can tell it is not possible to use the PS1 variable to update the title bar as well. `ESC` and `BEL` fail to set the title as one would expect if they were using bash or ksh

Here is my .shrc file

```
update_prompt() {
    case "$PWD" in
        "$HOME"*)
            pretty_pwd="~${PWD#*"${HOME}"}"
            ;;
        "/usr$HOME"*)
            pretty_pwd="~${PWD#*"/usr${HOME}"}"
            ;;
        *)
            pretty_pwd="$PWD"
            ;;
    esac

    case "$TERM" in
        xterm*|rxvt*)
            PS1="[$USER@\\h $pretty_pwd]\\$ "
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac

    printf "\\033]0;[%s@$(hostname -s): %s]\\007" "$USER" "$pretty_pwd"
}

update_prompt
```

So when I fire up a terminal or log in via ssh, it gives the pretty prompt that I like. But now I need this function to run every time that cd is executed and returns an exit status of 0.

I was going to use an alias that was something like:

```
alias cd="cd $1 && update_prompt"
```

but that was before I realized that aliases do not except arguments. How might I go about doing something like this?

Comment: BTW, the edge case of *root* and *toor* seems to be handled by `\$`. Here's the fragment from the [sh(1) manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh): *Superuser status.  `$ ` for normal users and `# ` for superusers.*

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Hey, thanks for reaching out. It probably wasn't fair to call the use of `toor` an edge case, as many FreeBSD users use the toor account to run a shell that is not part the the base FreeBSD. As per your suggestion, I tried removing the `|toor` and escaping the `$` in my code and it still yielded the same result when logging into the toor account. Might I ask to what you are referring to with the `\$`?

Comment: `\$` could be used the same way as `\h` in `PS1`. For example setting `PS1` to `\h \$` results in `\$` being replaced with either `# ` or `$ ` depending on if you're a root or no.

Comment: I am not sure if it works for the toor account :/

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski After further investigation, I can confirm that you are correct. I just made the mistake of using `\$` instead of `\\$` (you must use two '\' to escape when in double quotes). Very nice catch! Will update the code in a bit

Comment: Cool! Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function instead of an alias:

```
cd() {
  command cd "$@" && update_prompt
}
```

Just put it into `~/.shrc`. You have to use `command` here to let sh know that you are referring to the actual `cd` builtin command instead of the function you've just defined.

Refer to the [sh(1)](http://man.freebsd.org/sh/1) manual page for the details on how to make [sh(1)](http://man.freebsd.org/sh/1) source the `~/.shrc` file when it starts:

> Therefore, a user should place commands that are to be executed only at login
>   time in the `.profile` file, and commands that are executed for every shell
>   inside the `ENV` file.  The user can set the `ENV` variable to some file by placing
>   the following line in the file .profile in the home directory, substituting for
>   `.shrc` the filename desired:
>
> ```
> ENV=$HOME/.shrc; export ENV
> ```

I use this trick in my `cd` alias manager. Here's a link to the source code of the function: https://github.com/0mp/goat/blob/v2.5.0/libgoat.sh#L31-L57

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with alias+arguments if you swap the commands:

```
$ alias cd="echo change; cd"
$ pwd
/nas
$ cd /
change
$ pwd
/
$ cd /etc
change
$ pwd
/etc
$
```